# Eclipse Oxygen can't create virtual machine

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Hi I downloaded eclipse oxygen but I can't get it to work. It throws an error ''could not create Java virtual machine''. I tried changing 1024m to 512m and Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 to 1.6 but neither worked. ANY help is appreciated. At the time of this comment I was running java 1.7.0.25 but I updated
[Picture of error file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDkJg.png)

Comment: Which Java version do you have install (run `java -version` on the command line and add the result to your question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Oxygen recommends (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/?show_instructions=TRUE#page-download) or even **requires** (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation/Java8Required) Java 8.

Please **install Java 8** and make sure this is the version used (e.g. remove other versions or run the binary used with the parameter `-version`).

You may also want to reinstall Eclipse - your **`eclipse.ini` might be corrupt**. The line `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6-Xms256m` in the attached image most likely should be two lines...

You **should not have to change** parameters like `Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`. Especially **lowering** the required java version most likely **doesn't work** -  there's a reason why it is required. Giving Eclipse **more memory is hardly ever wrong**. Giving less memory than in the default setting usually doesn't work too well. If you don't have 1GB of free memory for Eclipse, you should try a less memory hungry IDE...

Answer (score 0):

Please do not downvote me for this but it seems you have a problem with java itself because if java could not create a virtual machine it means you do have the wrong java version. Same error was thrown for tomcat, fixed it with different java

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. My system initially had Java 7 and Kepler. That always worked. Then I added a new Java (Java 10) and a new Eclipse (i.e. Oxygen). With these two Java versions and two Eclipse versions on my machine. I couldn't invoke either Eclipse. Invoking Oxygen generated the error noted above. Invoking Kepler generated a different error.

So, to make a long story short, Oxygen worked when I deinstalled Java 7 and only had Java 10. Kepler worked when I deinstalled Java 10 and only had Java 7. And neither Eclipse worked when both Javas were installed. Perhaps there's a way to get it to all work when both Javas are installed, but for now, I just uninstalled Java 7 so I can get going with my project using the newer versions of Eclipse and Java.